# how to enumurate through CALayer Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to change the following to c# from c objective Xamarin.IOS

```
 NSEnumerator *enumerator = [rootLayer.sublayers reverseObjectEnumerator];
for(CALayer *layer in enumerator) {
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use System.Linq's `Reverse` as a replacement for the NSArray's `reverseObjectEnumerator` method:

Example:

```
foreach (var layer in View.Layer.Sublayers.Reverse())
{
    layer.RemoveFromSuperLayer();
}
```

> reverse​Object​Enumerator()
>
> Returns an enumerator object that lets you access each object in the array, in reverse order.

re: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1415734-reverseobjectenumerator

Comment: @bhuvana Can you accept the answer if that solved you question, thanks